# Guḍhī Pāḍavā or Ugadi: Day on which Universe is created?

Tags: puranas, brahma, festivals

Posting it on a day of Guḍhī Pāḍavā or Ugadi.
 I was reading the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudi_Padwa) link about this Hindu Festival.

It was mentioned in that link that on this day, Brahma created the universe as per Brahma Purana.

Can this be validated and what could be the significance of this particular day or "Tithi"?
 If this day is such an important day (because the universe itself was created), why in other parts of India (and not the other parts of world) this is NOT celebrated?

Also, it would be interesting to know if there is any other day as per Hinduism which is considered as the "day of universe creation".

Comment: I looked in the Brahma Purana, and at first glance I couldn't find such a statement.  [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=v4DKw7mlQw8C&lpg=PA77&dq=chaitra%20brahma%20creation&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q&f=false) claims to even give the specific verse of the Brahma Purana, but doing control F on the Sanskrit text of the Brahma Purana doesn't yield any results.  By the way, I've also heard claims that Akshaya Tritaya is the day that Brahma created the Universe, but I'm not sure if that has a scriptural basis either.

Comment: Ugadi means beginning of new era in which we are living now called as Kali Yuga. Kali Yuga started from the moment Lord Krishna left the world.
On this auspicious occasion, a special dish called Ugadi Pachadi is made which is a mixture of Neem buds, flowers, jaggery, raw mango, tamarind juice etc.